# How to enable minified JavaScript files in Play 2.3.1 templates?

Tags: javascript, playframework, sbt, minify, uglifyjs

I was able to load the sbt-uglify 1.0.3 plugin in my Play Framework 2.3.1 app. Loading of the non-minified javascripts is pretty straightforward, but loading the minified versions seems to be impossible.

In my template I use `<script>` tags similar to this:

```
<script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/app.js")"></script>
```

In dev mode, the non-minified javascript version is loaded, which is fine. In prod mode (using `activator start`) I see sbt-uglify generating the minified versions to the `target/web/uglify/build` folder, but because I didn't change the above `<script>` tag line in my templates, the non-minified versions of the javascripts files are loaded.

Is there a way to do a prod-only mapping of such routes to load the minified versions?

Answer (score 23):

The issue [Reverse Router should use minified assets in production automatically](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/pull/2973) was fixed in Play 2.3.1 that exactly matches your requirement.

According to [Play 2.3.1 Changelog](http://www.playframework.com/changelog):

> The behaviour of the Assets reverse router has changed, if minified
>   versions of assets exist, it now returns a URL for those instead. To
>   disable this behaviour, set `assets.checkForMinified=true` in
>   `application.conf`.

NOTE It should rather read *set `assets.checkForMinified=false`*, but anyway...

What follows works in **production mode** only so start the application with `activator start` not `run` or use the generated start scripts (after `stage`).

The behaviour of using minified versions of assets in **production** should be enabled by default in the version of Play with `@routes.Assets.versioned` (not `routes.Assets.at`).

It does require that the appropriate route declaration in `conf/routes` is:

```
GET  /assets/*file  controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file: Asset)
```

What I found a bit unclear at first was **the order** of elements in `pipelineStages` as well as the requirement to include [sbt-rjs](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-rjs) in it.

And just after I'd written the sentence about the order I found in the section "RequireJS" in [Play 2.3 Migration Guide](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Migration23):

> The order of stages is significant. You first want to optimize the
>   files, produce digests of them and then produce gzip versions of all
>   resultant assets.

I've also found in [Play 2.3 Migration Guide](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Migration23) in the section "Closure Compiler":

> UglifyJS 2 is presently provided via the RequireJS plugin (described
>   next). The intent in future is to provide a standalone UglifyJS 2
>   plugin also for situations where RequireJS is not used.

It all started with the answer to [Play 2.3 sbt-web plugin Javascript minification](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/play-framework/VQv_tjngCpM/6CngasazyvMJ).

So, the below `pipelineStages` is the working one - mind the order and `rjs`:

```
pipelineStages := Seq(rjs, uglify, digest, gzip)
```

`project/plugins.sbt` used was as follows:

```
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.3.5")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-digest" % "1.0.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-uglify" % "1.0.3")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-gzip" % "1.0.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-rjs" % "1.0.6")
```

Don't forget to create an empty `app/assets/javascripts/main.js` file to let `sbt-rjs` do its job.

As a test, I created a Play application with `activator new playApp play-scala` and applied the above changes in the build as well as in `app/views/main.scala.html` that ultimately looked as follows (note `@routes.Assets.versioned`):

```
@(title: String)(content: Html)

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>@title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.versioned("stylesheets/main.css")">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="@routes.Assets.versioned("images/favicon.png")">
        <script src="@routes.Assets.versioned("javascripts/hello.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        @content
    </body>
</html>
```

Executing `activator start` and calling `curl http://localhost:9000` gives (formatting's mine for the sake of readability):

```
➜  play-uglify  curl http://localhost:9000

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Welcome to Play</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="/assets/stylesheets/d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e-main.css">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/assets/images/84a01dc6c53f0d2a58a2f7ff9e17a294-favicon.png">
        <script src="/assets/javascripts/4302136334616ae0605d47a1932ee262-hello.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Your new application is ready.</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Note `4302136334616ae0605d47a1932ee262-hello.min.js` and the non-JavaScript resources digested.

Comment: I am also trying to use uglify.  However, I do not know how to start with Play.  If you have an example, can you please share?

Comment: I added uglify, digest, gzip to project + pipelineStages as you described. I also changed the '@routes.Assets.at' -> '@routes.Assets.versioned' in views. Starting my app using 'activator start' produces the minified javascripts, but the browser still loads the original, non-minified versions.

Comment: Hi @Jacek i follow all abouve steps that you mentioned. But when execute `activator start` command i am getting following error. `[info] Done packaging.
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unmatched closing ')' near index 47
['"]?([^\s'"]*)['"]?\s*:\s*[\[]?.*['"].*/lib\(.*)['"]`

Comment: This all works (thanks a lot!) but there is a small issue. Play default serves minified version (which is good) but the original source code is publicly available as well in: `/assets/javascripts/private-javascript-file.js.src.js`. Is there a way to remove these files and keep only minified and `.map` files?

Comment: I simply don't know and would recommend asking this question as a follow-up to this. I think it merits being a question on SO. Go for it!

Comment: So I managed to remove original unminified `.js` source files from final build by disabling generation of source maps using `RjsKeys.generateSourceMaps := false` in `build.sbt`.