# Using minified files in play application

Tags: playframework, sbt-rjs

I am using sbt-rjs,sbt-digest and sbt-gzip plugins for minification of files in play 2.4 application.The plugin minifies the files and keeps them in target->web->rjs folder of the application.
But when i run the application in production mode, it uses the same unminified files from the public folder.

Can anybody tell how to instruct play to use the minified files in production mode?

Comment: Possibly helpful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24581606/how-to-enable-minified-javascript-files-in-play-2-3-1-templates

Comment: @Nio Thanks. I ran through the process again and it worked.
I had seen the link earlier too, but i can't figure out what went wrong at that time.Now, it's using minified files in production mode.